# Java web application seems to go idle quickly in Tomcat

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm new to java and tomcat. I'm developing a website in java using spring mvc. It's deployed to a linux server that's running Tomcat 8. Everything works fine when I deploy, it connects to the database great. The issue is that the site seems to go idle very quickly. I haven't been able to time it exactly, but it seems like it only takes about a minute of inactivity for the entire site to go idle. Then the next request is extremely slow, loading in all my classes. I'm losing my sessions as well.

Is this a common occurrence? Does it sound like I'm doing something wrong in java? Tomcat? Both?

EDIT: In light of StuPointerException's comment, I've updated my database connection management. I'm now using Apache dbcp. I will update if this resolves the problem. I want to give my QA tester ample time to hit my site some more.

Comment: Are you using a connection pool to connect to your database?

Comment: I'm not sure of the underlying architecture, but I'm using a OracleDataSource for database connections, running queries through JDBC. I'm opening and closing connections when each query is run. It's worth pointing out that even loading up the login page (which doesn't connect to the database) is slow as well when idle.

Comment: It may be happening because of your cloud provider limitations. For instance, if you host an application on Heroku for free then your application will go sleep after 30 minutes of inactivity.

Comment: This is hosted on a network server and is being accessed internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer your question directly without more information about your server setup.

For what it's worth though, every time I see this kind of behaviour it's down to a mis-configured database connection pool.  There can be a significant overhead in creating new database connections.

If you don't use a connection pool or you're allowing connections in the pool to die (due to missing validation queries/checks) then you will start to see performance problems over time due to connection timeouts.

Comment: I definitely think the database connections could be a problem. I will do more research there. My main point is that this isn't default behavior for Tomcat, correct? Like a site shouldn't go idle in a minute. It seems like it's more a problem in my code rather than Tomcat configuration. Does that sound correct?

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer. In my update above, I wasn't using any kind of connection pool., I updated my database connection to use Apache DBCP, and performance has increased greatly. The site is running "normal", more or less, now. My QA tester is happy!

EDIT: Also, thank you for your help.